# adding multiple expected p-value lines lines to QQ-plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am wondering how I can plot a QQ plot with multiple p-value vectors for different studies in one plot.

I am using the following code to generate a QQ-plot:

```
install.packages("ggplot2") 
library(ggplot2)
```

The code for qq can be found here: http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2009/11/qq-plots-of-p-values-in-r-using-ggplot2.html

```
qq(data$Pvals, title="My Quantile-Quantile Plot")
```

Now I have 4 studies, so 4 $Pval vectors. I am able to add in the first Pval1 as : 
qq(data$Pval1, title="My Quantile-Quantile Plot")

How can I add labeled lines of observed p-values for the remaining studies? -> Pval2, Pval3, Pval4. Essentially I'd like to display the QQ-plot with 4 observed p-value lines representing the 4 studies in one graph.
Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you share how your data looks?  I think the answer you're looking for is defining the `group` variable in the `aes` string.  For instance,

UPDATE TO TRANSPOSE DATA SET

```
# install.packages('ggplot2')   # only needs to be installed first time
# install.packages('reshape2')  # only needs to be installed first time

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# fakeData
# RowNum Pval1 Pval2 Pval3 Pval4
#      1   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
#      2   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
#      3   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5
#
# melt(fakeData, id.vars = 'RowNum')
# RowNum variable value
#      1    Pval1   0.5
#      1    Pval2   0.5
#      1    Pval3   0.5
```

ORIGINAL CODE

```
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 50),
                 Number = sample(1:100, 200, replace = T))

ggplot(df, aes(sample = Number, group = Group, color = Group)) +
geom_point(stat = 'qq')
```

[image]

Comment: My data is a dataframe of 4 columns, each column contains p-value for a single study. It's really large so I cannot share it as a file. Columns are labeled "Pval1", "Pval2", "Pval3" and Pval4". It seems that to work with your code I would have to tranpose my data frame so the columns turn into rows? Would that work?

Comment: Yep, I think it would.  Try using the melt function from the reshape2 package, but you'll need one column to remain constant.  I'll edit my code in the example above to show you what I mean...

Comment: Wen I run the code above, I get **Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : 
  invalid graphics state**

Comment: You may have to install some pacakges if they're not on your machine, but you can type "install.packages('ggplot2')" and "install.packages('reshape2')" if you haven't downloaded them already.